# Why are most properties in js public?

Tags: javascript, properties, public

Im new in js and i wonder why nearly all properties in js are public.
I come from C++ and there i only programmed with private properties and access via getters and setters.

Comment: I think this is because JavaScript does not have any style guide. C++ and C# and other OOP-using languages have one to use. Also JavaScript isn't designed for oop as main purpose.

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski _JavaScript_ has prototyping and constructors, object literals, all of which are happy to take _functions_ or more _Objects_ as properties, this `this` keyword, you can define property enumerability and configurability. In fact, nearly everything in _JavaScript_ is an _Object_. How is this not OOP? The lack of _private_ properties is more because it works in a very different way; everything is about scope and closure.

Comment: If you are new to JavaScript, one great resource, in addition to the already linked resources, is the [**JavaScript MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) also one of Crockford's books "JavaScript_The_Good_Parts" is great as well.

Comment: if you're used to getters and setter you can still use them, you just ref vars instead of private properties; there's not much of a paractical difference between the two concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have simple keywords built into the language for makes properties private. You can use `var` for local variables (they won't be local if they're in the global scope though).

You can make things private by using the module pattern - http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

But because it's not as easy to make things private and requires a bit of ceremony with the all of the braces/closures required for making things private, some javascript projects will use naming conventions to do this (e.g. an underscore at the end of the variable name to indicate private) - google for example http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

The concept of public and private still exists, it's just implemented differently.